# Other objects that can be used to prove a variant of Cayley's theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So, first of all, it's not actually clear to me whether Cayley's theorem refers to:

1. every group $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of a symmetric group.
2. every group $G$ is the automorphism group of some mathematical object.

(2) implies (1), since we can get the permutation group on $G$ by simply forgetting the additional structure of the mathematical object in (2).

I'm talking about (2).

**I'm interested in other first-order structures besides sets being acted on by a group that can show that every group is the automorphism group of some first-order structure.**

Here's my attempt to summarize the proof of [Cayley's theorem given in this video by Richard Borcherds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZUDhtnz-Do). I'm using some language that doesn't appear in the video.

I'm trying to show that *every group is the automorphism group of some first-order structure*. Here's a construction for doing that using the group itself as a building material.

I have a group $G$.

For my language $L$, I choose the unary functions $r_\text{g}$ for each $g$ in $G$, which will be interpreted as right multiplication by $g$.

I will now define an $L$-structure $W$.

For my domain, I choose $G$.

Let each $r_g$ be interpreted as follows:

$$ r_g^W(h) = hg $$

where juxtaposition denotes multiplication in $G$.

I claim $G \cong \text{Aut}(W)$.

As proof that $G \subset \text{Aut}(W)$.

$G$ acts on $W$ by left multiplication, denoted by $\vartriangleright : G \times W \to W$.

$$ g \vartriangleright h = gh $$

And $r_l(g \vartriangleright h) = ghl = g \vartriangleright (r_l h)$, so $g \vartriangleright \bigcirc$ is indeed a homomorphism.

As proof that $\text{Aut}(W) \subset G$, suppose we had an arbitrary homomorphism $\varphi$.

$\varphi(1) = g$ for some $g$.

For an arbitrary $h$, $\varphi(h) = \varphi(r_h(1)) = r_h(\varphi(1)) = gh$.

Thus $\varphi$ is completely determined by where it sends $1$.

Thus $\text{Aut}(W) \cong G$.

**This construction, however, is a little bit confusing because you have to use the group $G$ in three different ways. As the domain of the structure, as the right actions, and as left actions. I'm curious if there are other first-order structures that can be used to show that every group is the automorphism group of some first-order structure in such a way that the proof is easy to follow.**

For example, we know that this can be done for simple graphs by [Frucht's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frucht%27s%5Ftheorem#Proof_idea), which uses the fact that a group acts on its Cayley graph.

The proof here seems complicated and to involve a lot of details related to encoding colors into a simple graph, but it also seems like a theory of multi-colored directed graphs could be used to simply *encode the Cayley graph*, which would be preserved by left multiplication. It is not immediately clear to me that you wouldn't get *stray automorphisms not corresponding to left multiplication by any fixed element, though*.